# Why is only home page on my website showing when deployed on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have made a simple rails website and pushed to git and deployed through heroku. The only page which shows is the home page. here is the routes file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'handm#home'
  get 'handm/about'
  get 'handm/contact'
  get 'handm/industries'
  get 'handm/languages'
  get 'handm/services'
end
```

what could be causing the pages "not to exist"? thanks for your help.

Comment: run "heroku logs --tail" and then view the page, it should show you the error in the terminal, if you can't debug from that then paste parts of the log,  the first 10-20 lines should be fine.

Comment: @RockwellRice.  first few lines of result of "heroku logs --tail"

Comment: I beilieve your app is fine, the url right now is "/handm/about"  not "/about" which I bet is what you are viewing. This is it right? http://afternoon-tor-17057.herokuapp.com/handm/about.

Comment: actually it is just on https://afternoon-tor-17057.herokuapp.com/  not followed by anything.

Comment: Well but you are asking about the other pages, why they are broken when you try to view them, right?  The urls linked to in you navbar do not exists.  Also, make sure you change the route for the home link to "/" instead of home.  If you want to remove the "hamdm" part from the url let me know and I can explain how to do that.

Comment: sorry , could you clarify what you mean by changing the route for the home link?  which part do I need to change? from what to what?  Re: the handm part.  as I understand this is the name of my controller. is it necessary to remove it?

Comment: See my answer below, that should fix this for you.  You can remove the log stuff you posted as well, it is not needed after all and will make the post more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes in your navbar and the routes defined in your file are different.

This route

```
get 'handm/about'
```

Creates a url at **your_app_name/handm/about**

If you just want **your_app_name/about**, which is the link in the navbar, then change it to this in your route file.

```
get 'about', to: 'handm#about'
```

What this does is it names the route **/about** and points it to your controller and action with "to: handm#about".  You will need to switch over each of the routes in this way, not the root through, leave that as is.

When you switch that over, push to git and redeploy to heroku your links should work as is.

Comment: routes file now changed. to read get 'about' => 'handm#about' etc. I followed another poster's suggestion before I saw your answer, but I believe these are equivalent.  it improbved the situation by adding /about, /sevices etc to the end of the URL but the pages still "do not exist". the procedure I followed was 1.change the routes file. 2, git push origin master" 3. git push heroku master.

Comment: Looks like it is working now, remeber to change the "home" link in the navbar to "/" instead of "/home.html" in the html file.

Comment: routes file now changed. to read get 'about' => 'handm#about' etc. I followed another poster's suggestion before I saw your answer, but I believe these are equivalent.  now all the pages work EXCEPT the home page. whereas before it was only the home page that worked. (EDIT; you answered this question at the same time I posted it)

Comment: You have to change the route linked to in the a tag to "/" instead of "/home.html", this is in the navbar.

Comment: I am still not clear by what you mean by "change the home link in the navbar to "/" instead of /home.html". In which file am I making this change?

Comment: In your view file there should be something like this, "<a href="home.html">Home</a>"  You need to change that from "home.html" to just "/" so, "<a href="/">Home</a>"

Comment: sorry, now I understand. the change is in the application html file. now all the pages work.  thank you very much. I ve been going round in circles for days with this.

Comment: If you are just learning I would suggest this tutorial, it is pretty in depth so it will take time but worth it, https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Answer (score 0):

You haven't define routes properly. In get route you need to provide controller and action as well.

Try change `get 'handm/about'` to `get 'handm/about', to: 'handm#about'` . Do same for other as well. Hope this works.

Comment: this changed the web address on all the different pages. i.e. put / about, /services etc at the end of the URL. however there is still no content to the page.

Comment: Because root will automatically equivalent to get '/' and for rest you need to provide controller#action that's why home working fine and other not. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your named routes, you just haven't given them a controller method to route through. Try this:

```
get 'industries', to: 'handm#industries'
```

You are confusing the following routes - as they are not the same:

```
www.herokuapp.com/handm/industries & www.herokuapp.com/industries
```

Keep in mind that new to Rails 5.1 is direct routing which works as follows in your app's route file:

```
direct(:industries) { "http://www.example.com/industries" }
```

Creates the following rails method:

```
>> industries_url
```

which will now route the browser to:

```
http://www.example.com/industries
```

This is a very easy technique for use for beginner's as all you provide is the helper name and a raw url. You are rewarded with a helper method (indstries_url) to use anywhere in your app as a link_to